Italian movie that starts with a boy discovering a body
I would like to find the name of an Italian movie that starts with four boys chasing in the rye and than one of them (near an abandoned building) finds a body. It is supposed to be quite famous and is made ot he basis of an equally famous Italian novel.
I just saw the opening scene of the movie. There are four boys and two girls, one is the sister of one of the boys. They play a game, chasing and the looser has to be punished. First, one of the girls is supposed to be punished and she should get naked but than the main character jumps in and his punishment is to climb this abandoned building. This is how he discovers the body. But it is an Italian movie, so it's not Stand by me. And based on the Italian novel. Oh and I believe the name of one of the boys is a "rat" or something similar.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

It sounds really similar to "Stand By Me" (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092005/). It fits the description of 4 boys being chased, and them finding a dead body. As well as it being based off a famous Novel (in this case by Steven King).

Well I just saw the opening scene of the movie. There are four boys and two girls, one is the sister of one of the boys. They play a game, chasing and the looser has to be punished. First, one of the girls is supposed to be punished and she should get naked but than the main character jumps in and his punishment is to climb this abandoned building. This is how he discovers the body. But it is an Italian movie, so it's not Stand by me. And based on the Italian novel. Oh and I believe the name of one of the boys is a "rat" or something similar.

Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

From your description in the second post it seems like you are looking for "Io non ho paura" (I'm Not afraid) directed by Gabriele Salvatores based on the namesake novel by also italian writer Niccolò Ammaniti.
By the way, the group of boys accidentally stumble upon the hole in which a kidnapped boy of their age has been put, not on a corpse.

A good book and a good movie in my opinion

Yes, that's it. Many thanks for you reply. I am sure going to watch it now that I know which one it is :) and also congrats on you knowledge.

@user23586  You're very welcome ;) And if you should like it I suggest you also give it a try to Educazione Siberiana, same director, starring John Malkovic ( http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1697064/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
